# What's wrong with this sed?

Tags: sed

I'd like to modify the IP address for 'relvir':

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   debian-foo.jimnet debian-foo

54.218.208.77   server1
31.187.98.19    machine2
51.39.207.120   relvir

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

I'm trying to do it like this, but I don't understand why it isn't working:

```
cat sedtest | sed 's/.+relvir$/1.2.3.4 relvir/'
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `.+` is not understandable by sed, make that `.*` or invoke sed with `-E` to turn on extended regexes.

Comment: ... or use `c` instead of `s` when you want to **c**hange a whole line e.g. `sed '/relvir$/ c\1.2.3.4 relvir'`

Answer (score 2):

With *basic regular expressions* ***sed*** will treat `+` literally, to perform the needed substitution use `*` quntifier:

```
cat sedtest | sed 's/.*relvir$/1.2.3.4 relvir/'
```

To proceed treating `+` as quantifier use *extended regular expressions* applying `-E` option:

```
cat sedtest | sed -E 's/.+relvir$/1.2.3.4 relvir/'
```

Comment: You beat me to it good sir!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are looking for

> cat sedtest | sed 's/.\+relvir$/1.2.3.4 relvir/'

Comment: I'm trying hard, but I can't find the difference

Comment: Opps it should have read  .\+  SE markdown ate the "\" I have corrected for this and edited my reply.

Comment: Please note that `\+` is undefined in POSIX and most implementations like FreeBSD `sed` will not understand it. But a simple `..*` has the same meaning and is portable.